# Editing posts: blank spaces to 'bypass' character minimum

Tags: discussion, edits

Are blank spaces to bypass the minimum amount of required characters allowed? For example, [this here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15154305) is one of my recent approved edits, I only *actually* edited 1 character to correct the title of the question, and had to add blank spaces to be allowed to make the edit. Since it's approved, I assume it's allowed, but I'd like to know for sure!

Comment: That edit should have been rejected. It was only approved because the person who originally posted the question saw it and approved it. They have a binding vote. He probably didn't notice that you had added useless whitespace, just saw that you had fixed the typo, and clicked Approve. One hopes that other reviewers would be more diligent. This is considered abuse, and if you keep doing it, a moderator will surely step in and give you a time out from editing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's almost always something else to fix. In this particular case the words

> Thank you for any help.

are not required and you could and should have removed them which would have put you well over the 6 character limit.

Adding random whitespace is undesirable and unnecessary.

Comment: Alright, I didn't know I could remove things like that. That'll definitely help out in the future! Thanks for your answer.

Comment: FYI @Metoniem https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Answer (score 5):

Allowed or disallowed is perhaps too strict for this issue. But please don't do that. Generally there are more things to fix in a post than just the one issue you saw. For example, the user wrote

> but I will need to expand **to to** other cases

and he included

> Thank you for any help.

The first one can be fixed, the latter should probably be removed. And that takes you over the minimum edit amount. So please don't just add random whitespaces to a post to get you over the edit threshold. If I were to see such an edit, I would reject it.